# How to show a div when the enter key has been pressed in two textareas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

How do you detect that the enter key was pressed in two `textareas`? I have a way to detect the enter key was pressed in one `textarea` and need help with detecting the enter key was pressed in two `textareas`.

This is what I've done so far:

```js
$('#test1').keyup(function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#GFG_DOWN").text("Enter key pressed inside textarea");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="test1"></textarea>
        <textarea id="test2"></textarea>
        <br>     
          
        <p id = "GFG_DOWN" style = 
            "color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
        </p>
```

Comment: simultaneously?

Comment: Not at the same time but yes, enter key pressed in textarea 1 and textarea2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you must handle this with two FlagVariables.

```js
let text1Flag = false;
let text2Flag = false;

function callbackHandler(e, textType) {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (textType == 1) {
            text1Flag = true;
        } else {
            text2Flag = true;
        }
        if (text1Flag && text2Flag) {
           $("#GFG_DOWN").text("Enter key pressed inside textarea");
            text1Flag = false;
            text2Flag = false;
        }
   }
}

$("#test1").keyup((ev) => callbackHandler(ev, 1));
$("#test2").keyup((ev) => callbackHandler(ev, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="test1"></textarea>
        <textarea id="test2"></textarea>
        <br>     
          
        <p id = "GFG_DOWN" style = 
            "color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
        </p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is will help a lot and a great starting point.